# Primefaces XLS data exporter not working after primefaces upgrade to 8

Tags: primefaces

Upgraded primefaces from  5.3.6 to 8 version in application.After upgradation primefaces xls data exporter giving below error if I try to use it.Pdf exporter working fine.Is it necessary to upgrade poi version to 4.1.1 version to data exporter work fine?

Exception: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.setAlignment(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/HorizontalAlignment;)V

Current poi version is 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes see migration guide: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide#70-to-80

*Apache POI minimum version 4.1.1 to use Excel export*

This was done because there were multiple security CVE's reported against POI < 4.1.